# SQL Server Replace function return question marks for non english characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, localization, collation

My stored procedure has parameter `@Name nvarchar(250)`

It do some insert procedure after that, select some `nvarchar(250)` text from another table into variable `@msg nvarchar(300)`.

Then I replace part of this text in `@msg` with the `@Name` variable:

```
set @msg = REPLACE(@msg, '[contentname]', @Name)
```

The result is @Name is replaced as question marks when using another language than English

I have tried

```
REPLACE(@msg, '[contentname]', @Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

when I user print `@Name` it displays the non-english/Arabic text correctly

Can anybody give me ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: How do you set the value of @Name? e.g. do you execute the stored procedure like `exec myProc @Name = N'XXXXXXX';`? My first guess would just be that you're setting the value of @Name without the N prefix.

Comment: I execute the procedure using @Name=  N'XXXXXX' with N prefix but it doesn't help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a `NVARCHAR` string **literal**, then  you need to prefix it with a `N` character:

```
set @msg = REPLACE(@msg, N'[contentname]', @Name)
```

Otherwise, if you don't do this, SQL Server will most likely convert everything to `VARCHAR` (since you omitted the `N` prefix).